# Extract data from notion using python

Tags: python

I'm using **Notion** to store my data {client name, subscription...} in **tables**.

I want to extract some data using python but I can't figure out how.

For example count the total number of clients, get the total amount of subscriptions...

Could you please suggest a way to help me.

Comment: I know it is not really an answer but it could help. Have a look here:
https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py

Answer (score 2):

For fetching the data you can use `notion-client`. The great thing about it is that it supports both sync and async interfaces. What it lacks, though, is an easy way to navigate the data's structure (which is quite complicated in Notion)

For that you can use `basic-notion`. It allows you to use model classes to easily access all the properties and attributes of your Notion objects - kind of like you would with an ORM.

In your case the code might look something like this:

```
from notion_client import Client

from basic_notion.query import Query
from basic_notion.page import NotionPage, NotionPageList
from basic_notion.field import SelectField, TitleField, NumberField

# First define models

class MyRow(NotionPage):
    name = TitleField(property_name='Name')
    subscription = SelectField(property_name='Subscription')
    some_number = NumberField(property_name='Some Number')
    # ... your other fields go here
    # See your database's schema and the available field classes
    # in basic_notion.field to define this correctly.

class MyData(NotionPageList[MyRow]):
    ITEM_CLS = MyRow

# You need to create an integration and get an API token from Notion:
NOTION_TOKEN = '<your-notion-api-token>'
DATABASE_ID = '<your-database-ID>'

# Now you can fetch the data

def get_data(database_id: str) -> MyData:
    client = Client(auth=NOTION_TOKEN)
    data = client.databases.query(
        **Query(database_id=database_id).filter(
            # Some filter here
            MyRow.name.filter.starts_with('John')
        ).sorts(
            # You can sort it here
            MyRow.name.sort.ascending
        ).serialize()
    )
    return MyData(data=data)


my_data = get_data()
for row in my_data.items():
    print(f'{row.name.get_text()} - {row.some_number.number}')
# Do whatever else you may need to do
```

For more info, examples and docs see:

- notion-client: https://github.com/ramnes/notion-sdk-py
- basic-notion: https://github.com/altvod/basic-notion
- Notion API Reference: https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this only once - you can export a notion page (database) to HTML, which will probably be easier to extract from.
If you want this as a weekly/daily/monthly thing - I can't help with doing that in python but zapier and automate.io would be perfect.